# react native navigation - Change Android navIcon

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using Airbnb's [native navigation library](https://github.com/airbnb/native-navigation) for navigation bars, specifically `Navigator.Config`. On Android, I want to replace the default back button by this [material icon](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=close&style=baseline) on a screen that is presented like a modal. I have tried setting a new icon using the navIcon prop of `Navigator.Config`, but Android does not recognize any URI I give e.g. `../icons/icon.png`.

Is there a way to set another Android back icon from the JS side, or from the Android side?

EDIT: Precised that the screen is presented as a modal

Comment: Why?  People are used to the back button looking like the back button looks on their phone.  Changing it is a lot of effort for something that will at best not be noticed, and at worst cause confusion.  System icons should be left alone, so that users get continuity with the rest of their apps.

Comment: @GabeSechan you are right in general, I forgot to mention that the screen I am talking about is a modal displayed for filtering content, and the close button better matches the filtering behaviour

Comment: You're probably going to need to write some XML